# I want formatted output to be display in shell script

Tags: shell

follwing is the script

```
echo "Starting of COUNT\n"
                echo " PPDF             SIZE            FILENAME   "
                for i in `cat $Input_File`
                do
                find $i -name *.pdf |wc -l;cd $(echo $i |sed -n 's/.*\(\/pdf.*\)/\1/p');du -sm $(echo "$i"|cut -f 9 -d /).tar.gz;
                done
```

The output now it shows as,
Starting of COUNT
[image]

But I want the output should be displayed as column wise as below 
[image]

Comment: Did you try `\t`?

Answer (score 0):

your command is too noisy to clearly point the issue, but you can see what you need to fix from the example below

```
$ echo -e "firts\t" | sed 's/ts/st/'; echo "second"
first
second

$ echo -en "firts\t" | sed 's/ts/st/'; echo "second"
first   second
```

in summary `-n` option for `echo` suppresses the new line.